# Which PHP 5 Version is most commonly used?

Tags: php, hosting, shared-hosting

When I'm developing applications that would be used on client web serves of different configurations, often with shared hosting, which PHP 5 version should I assume most web servers have, e.g 5.2.x, 5.3.x, etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version 5.2 is used by 84.9% of all the websites who use PHP version 5.

Version 5.3.3 is used by 39.7% of all the websites who use PHP version 5.3

You can see more statistical data from the following link:

http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/5.3/all

Comment: Seems like 5.2 is 84.9% and 5.3 is 7.5%

Comment: Cheap web hosting providers usually provide 5.2.x, I personally only need 5.2+ for my http://thinphp.com framework to use filter_var() & input sanitizing...

Comment: All our servers run remi 5.3.6

Comment: Dammit 15.3% still using 5.2

Answer (score 0):

WordPress.org also collects stats about installs, you can see results here: [WP stats](http://wordpress.org/about/stats/)

August 2014 it it 78% for 5.2 & 5.3 which are supposed EOL.